# Can someone clear up my Git confusion regarding remotes?

Tags: git, github

Recently, I cloned the Laravel framework repo on Git for developing my own app locally. I did not Fork the repo. I now would like to stage my app on my Git account, and sync with it. I would also like to still be able to pull Laravel framework updates to my local repo. I'm unclear how to set this up.

I am using GitHub App for Mac. In Settings for my local repo, https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git is listed as the Primary Remote Repo (origin).

When I run a Sync, it looks like the "origin" laravel repo is updating my local repo. Correct?
Without having originally forked Laravel, are my own local changes being pushed anywhere?

My goal is to continue to be able to get Laravel updates on my local repo, but to also create a repo in my Git account to sync my app with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, you need 2 remotes. One remote you already have by way of cloning from the Larvel framework repo. This would have also created a local branch called master as well. This local branch called master tracks the remote larvel framework branch

Now add another remote

```
git remote add your_origin <your guthub url>
```

Create a branch off your larvel branch and name it such that you understand that its your branch

```
git checkout -b your_branch
```

Now push your changes to your remote by

```
git push your_origin your_branch
```

So now you have 2 remotes and 2 local branches set up.

In order to pull from the larvel repo. Do the below

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

Sync that with your branch by

```
git checkout your_branch
git merge master
git push your_origin your_branch
```

Think this would help with what you are trying to do.

Comment: So I see that the local branch from the laravel repo is 'master' and I can pull to it from the 'origin' to remain updated, which is what is happening in my Sync. I can then also add a remote to my own git repo, using a name I give it, like "staging". I then checkout my local repo as a new branch, say called "local." And I push my "local" repo to my "staging" remote. Do I have that right?

Comment: Yup.. going by the names you are suggesting.. just put "local" wherever I said your_branch and "staging" whereever I said your_origin

Answer (score 1):

You need to establish two remotes: `origin`, which will point to your repo on GitHub and `upstream`, which will point to https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git

The easier way would be to fork `laravel` repo on gihub, pull it locally, merge your changes into that repository, then delete original pull from `larvel/laravel.git`

`git` is very forgiving, I would recommend to experiment more with it, and make yourself comfortable with the tool.

I found this article helpful: [Git Forks And Upstreams: How-to and a cool tip](https://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/07/git-upstreams-forks/)